# How to only call ACCEPT if the substitution variable is undefined?

Tags: oracle, user-input, sqlplus

I have a few scripts to run and each one uses the same substitution variable. At the top of each script, I have:

```
ACCEPT COFFEE CHAR PROMPT 'Please indicate your preferred coffee brand: ';
```

To avoid having to enter the type of coffee for every script, I could simply rely on the default behaviour when using `&&COFFEE..` everywhere. However, this just gets me a prompt of `Enter value for coffee`, which is less friendly.

I'm curious. Is there a way to check whether COFFEE is already defined, and only call `ACCEPT...` if it's not?

I have this at the moment:

```
IF COFFEE IS NULL THEN
    ACCEPT COFFEE CHAR PROMPT 'Please indicate your preferred coffee brand: ';
END IF;
```

However, when I run this in SQLPlus, I get the following error:

```
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "IF COFFEE I..." - rest of line ignored.
```

*Variable names have been changed to protect the innocent...*

I've had a good Google and a search through this site for the answer, but haven't found it. I suspect it's not possible, as I've read answers here that highlight the limits of PL/SQL and SQLPlus.

Answer (score 0):

If a variable isn't defined and you try to use the variable then it will prompt:

```
SQL> define var1='defined'
SQL> select '&var1' from dual;
old   1: select '&var1' from dual
new   1: select 'defined' from dual

'DEFINE
-------
defined

SQL> select '&var2' from dual;
Enter value for var2: var2
old   1: select '&var2' from dual
new   1: select 'var2' from dual

'VAR
----
var2
```

If you define a variable explicitly then it will be re-used, however prompted ones will not persist:

```
SQL> define var1='SYS'
SQL> select username from dba_users where username = '&var1';
old   1: select username from dba_users where username = '&var1'
new   1: select username from dba_users where username = 'SYS'

USERNAME
------------------------------
SYS

SQL> select username from dba_users where username = '&var1';
old   1: select username from dba_users where username = '&var1'
new   1: select username from dba_users where username = 'SYS'

USERNAME
------------------------------
SYS

SQL> select username from dba_users where username = '&var2';
Enter value for var2: SYSTEM
old   1: select username from dba_users where username = '&var2'
new   1: select username from dba_users where username = 'SYSTEM'

USERNAME
------------------------------
SYSTEM

SQL> select username from dba_users where username = '&var2';
Enter value for var2: SYS
old   1: select username from dba_users where username = '&var2'
new   1: select username from dba_users where username = 'SYS'

USERNAME
------------------------------
SYS
```

If you use && then it will prompt if unset and PERSIST

```
SQL> select username from dba_users where username = '&&var3';
Enter value for var3: SYS
old   1: select username from dba_users where username = '&&var3'
new   1: select username from dba_users where username = 'SYS'

USERNAME
------------------------------
SYS

SQL> select username from dba_users where username = '&&var3';
old   1: select username from dba_users where username = '&&var3'
new   1: select username from dba_users where username = 'SYS'

USERNAME
------------------------------
SYS

SQL>  select username from dba_users where username = '&var3';
old   1:  select username from dba_users where username = '&var3'
new   1:  select username from dba_users where username = 'SYS'

USERNAME
------------------------------
SYS
```

Not really asked but you can clear a declared variable by using UNDEFINE, and not, as you might expect, by setting it to 'NULL':

```
SQL> define var3=NULL;
SQL> select username from dba_users where username = '&var3';
old   1: select username from dba_users where username = '&var3'
new   1: select username from dba_users where username = 'NULL'
SQL> undefine var3;
SQL>  select username from dba_users where username = '&var3';
Enter value for var3: SYS
old   1:  select username from dba_users where username = '&var3'
new   1:  select username from dba_users where username = 'SYS'

USERNAME
------------------------------
SYS
```